# Json parse error when parsing an object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Hi all i have an JSON Object which i am trying to parse it in jquery but when i try to parse it i get an erro saying

```
        JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
```

here is my json  object

```
         {
         "StoreId": 20314,
         "DisplayDateFomratId": null,
         "EnableSearchSuggest": null,
         "DefaultProductSort": null,
         "CompanyTollfreeNumber": null,
         "FavIcon": null,
         "StoreLogo": null,
         "UseExpressCheckout": null,
         "UsersMustLoginToseePricing": null,
         "CallForPricing": null,
         "StoreName": "RA",
         "CompanyName": null,
         "SSLDomainName": "localhost: 4445",
         "DomainName": "localhost: 4445",
         "StoreAddressId": 20840,
         "TomeZoneId": 10152,
         "DateFormatId": 10152,
         "CartQuantityBoxesId": 10192,
         "ProductDisplayModeId": 10187,
         "SearchTypeId": 10193,
         "DownForMaintenance": false,
         "ShowThumbnailsInCart": null,
         "ShowProductPrice": true,
         "EnableWishlist": true,
         "ShowEstimatedShippingInCart": null,
         "ShowEstimatedTaxInCart": true,
         "AllowReturns": false,
         "AlternativeProductDisplay": true,
         "HideAddToCartWhenNoStock": false,
         "LoginToRequestQuote": null,
         "AddTocartToSeePricing": false,
         "ShowProductWarranty": false,
         "EnableNewProducts": true,
         "EnableFeaturedProducts": true,
         "EnableTopSellers": true,
         "AllowGiftWrapping": false,
         "DoNotAllowBackOrders": false,
         "DownTimeMessage": "",
         "StoreProductDesc": null,
         "SEOScript": null,
         "MetaTitle": "Radians\u001fInc.",
         "MetaDescription": "Radians\u001fInc.",
         "MetaKeywords": "Radians\u001fInc."
        }
```

when i am trying to acces this Model object via

```
         var settings = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))');
```

and in the above statement my "@Model" has the object and how do i escape those ' with "\".

Comment: if `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))` is returning the json you mentioned previously, it should work. What is instead being returned?

Comment: i have a model in my object , i am not able to access it untill i parse it with JSON

Comment: @KevinB can you look at the jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/XVB3Q/1/]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `JSON.parse` and also quotes. Just use.

```
var settings = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

[**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.